# How do I replace an Australian light switch?

Tags: wiring, switch

I'm trying to replace my light switch with a new one. The switch has two switches on it. The replacement switch I bought has two switches but is slightly different than the old one. This as far as I can work out is because the bottom switch is a two way switch. Will I be able to use this new switch?

[image: Old Switch]

[image: New Switch]

Comment: You can use a 3 way switch for a 2 way. Are you sure it is a 2 way I see 3 sets of wires on each switch. Over here in the US many times I find a white wire used as a traveler for a 3 way and not marked.

Comment: You need to turn your screwdriver upside down.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; just wire it up as it is now. The terminals should be labeled the same.

Note that US/Canada and the rest of the world have different definitions for 2/3 way - in Aus, 'two way' means a light that is controlled by two switches, while in the US, that would be called 'three way', because each switch has three connections.

Comment: The UK also uses the same terms as Aussies - two-way switches normally means two switches controlling one light. In electrical engineering terms, we call a Single Pole **Double** Throw ([SPDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_terminology)) switch a "two-way" switch.